# How to wget files and save as domain name?

Tags: shell, wget, gnu-parallel

Here's what I'm currently running to wget files:

```
parallel -a list.txt --jobs 100 wget -P /home/files/
```

The `list.txt` file contains a list of files such as this:

```
example.com/test.html
anotherexample.com/test.html
sample.com/test.html
```

However, it wants to save every file as `test.html`, obviously.

What I'm trying to do is figure out how to edit the above command to save each file as the domain name.  So it should save it as the text before the `/` symbol.  Like this:

```
example.com
anotherexample.com
sample.com
```

Does anyone know of any easy way to do this so I can still run it in parallel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could first transform the addresses in `list.txt` and specify the output file of `wget` explicitly, i.e., something like this:

```
parallel -a list.txt --jobs 100 'g=$(echo {1} | tr "/" "_");wget -P /home/files -O $g {1}'
```

Here, `{1}` stands for the argument extracted by `parallel` from the input list and all `/` are simply replaced with `_`. To keep only characters before the first `/`, one could do

```
parallel -a list.txt --jobs 100 'g=$(echo {1} | sed "s#/.*##");wget -P /home/files -O $g {1}'
```